# Saving a list into a json with DateTime as a Header

Tags: json, unity-game-engine

i don't know if I'm explaining it right but what i want is to be able to save 3 lists of strings but have them separated based on time. The idea is to store some strings for each day and save them into a json so i can search for the date and display them into a calendar.

My try was like so

```
[Serializable]
public class TimeStamp
{
    public string CreatedDate;
    public List<Entries> day = new List<Entries>();
}

[Serializable]
public class Entries
{
    public List<string> names = new List<string>();
    public List<string> location = new List<string>();
    public List<string> info = new List<string>();
}
```

which then i saved like so

```
 string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(timeStamp);
        try
        {
            timeStamp.CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow.ToLocalTime().ToString("dd-MM-yyyy   HH:mm");
            File.WriteAllText(Application.persistentDataPath + "/Journal.json", json);
            Debug.Log("Data Saved");
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Log("Error Saving Data:" + e);
            throw;
        }
```

Which does save everything i need but its not separated by the date, trying to explain it the way i think of it is that i want the date to be the "header" of the Json so in one Json file i would have all entries for each day and also i made them into a list so i can add or remove strings.

So later on when i want to add something i would search for the date and access the names list for instance and .Add() my string to that list

In a rather crude way this is how i would like my json to look like:

```
entries 
[
   "date"[
           list1 = []
           list2 = []
           list3 = []
         ]          
]
```

The way i feel like it should be is something like this

```
[Serializable]
public class Roots
{
    public TimeStamp timeStamp;
}

[Serializable]
public class TimeStamp
{
    public List<Entries> entries;
}

[Serializable]
public class Entries
{
    public List<string> names = new List<string>();
    public List<string> location = new List<string>();
    public List<string> info = new List<string>();
}
```

which gives a json like this

```
{
  "Entries": {
    "Timestamp": [
      {
        "names": "",
        "location": "",
        "info": ""
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

but how can i make that Timestamp be a string or a date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you actually rather want to have a collection class like

```
[Serializable] 
public class Root 
{ 
    public List<TimeStamp> timestamps = new List<TimeStamp>();
}
```

and rather add your individual timestamps to that list e.g.

```
// Probably you would load this from JSON at start of your app
private Root root = new Root();

...

root.timeStamps.Add(new TimeStamp(...));
```

And then

```
string json = JsonnUtility.ToJson(root);
...
```

---

So just the way you already have with

```
[Serializable]
public class TimeStamp
{
    public string CreatedDate;
    public List<Entries> day = new List<Entries>();
}

[Serializable]
public class Entries
{
    public List<string> names = new List<string>();
    public List<string> location = new List<string>();
    public List<string> info = new List<string>();
}
```

This should give you a JSON looking like

```
{
    "timestamps" : 
    [
        {
            "CreatedDate" : "12-04-2021   12:34",
            "day" : 
            [
                {
                    "names" : ["Guy1", "Dude2", "Jack3"],
                    "location" : ["Room1", "Place2", "Location3"],
                    "info" : ["This", "is", "some", "info"]
                },
                {
                    "names" : [...],
                    "location" : [...],
                    "info" : [...]
                },
                ...
            ]
        },

        {
            "CreatedDate" : "13-07-2021   14:42",
            "day" : 
            [
                {
                    "names" : [...],
                    "location" : [...],
                    "info" : [...]
                },
                ...
            ]
        },

        ...
    ]
}
```

---

If your goal was rather to actually have something like

```
{
    "timestamps" : 
    [
        {
            "12-04-2021   12:34": 
            {
                [
                    {
                        "names" : ["Guy1", "Dude2", "Jack3"],
                        "location" : ["Room1", "Place2", "Location3"],
                        "info" : ["This", "is", "some", "info"]
                    },
                    ...
                ]
            }
        },

        {
            "13-07-2021   14:42" :
            {
                [
                    {
                        "names" : [...],
                        "location" : [...],
                        "info" : [...]
                    },
                    ...
                ]
            }
        },

        ...
    ]
}
```

then you will need to rather use soemthing like

```
[Serializable]
public class Root
{
    public Dictionary<string, List<Entries>> timestamps = new Dictionary<string, List<Entries>>();
}

[Serializable]
public class Entries
{
    public List<string> names = new List<string>();
    public List<string> location = new List<string>();
    public List<string> info = new List<string>();
}
```

but this is not supported by the built-in JsonUtility and you would rather need to use e.g. [`Newtonsoft JSON.NET`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) (which is available as a [Unity Package](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.nuget.newtonsoft-json@2.0/manual/index.html)) and see in particular [Serializing a Dictionary](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeDictionary.htm)

Comment: i see thank you for your answer but how would i go about adding a string with the date to differentiate it? i have edited my post to show a sample of how the json would look like

Comment: @stratosla as I see this already should .. see the update at the bottom of my answer ... if you do not want it to say "CreatedDate : ..." but rather directly having something like `"12-04-2021   12:34" : { Entries : [...] }` then what you need to use would be a `Dictionary<string, List<Entries>` ... however, this is not supported by the builtin JsonUtility .. you would rather need to use e.g. Newtonsoft JSON .NET

Comment: Thank you the first one did the trick and managed to save everything i need into a json, but will look at the second example too! I did try to serialize and deserialize with newtonsoft too but found it a bit difficult to implement but will give it a shot too! Also if im not pushing my luck here , i cant seem to be able to add to each list like so so like add to the names list the strings would you mind if its not too much to help me out or should i open another thread?